# To display split and display the string value in 2 input fields

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have 2 fields called `hours` and `minutes`, Which I'm concatenating and storing in a variable  called `duration`:

The **JSON** Looks like this:

```
  [
   {
    "displayName": "Car Rent",
    "duration": "06:27:00",
   },
   {
    "displayName": "Bike Rent",
    "duration": "10:15:00",
   },
   {
    "displayName": "Texi Rent",
    "duration": "05:30:00",
   },
  ]
```

Component CODE:

**HTML**

```
  <form [formGroup]="addForm">

        <div>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Hours" formControlName="hours" required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <div>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Minutes" formControlName="minutes" required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>

      <button mat-flat-button  type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Save</button>
  </form>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from './contacts.service';
import {
FormBuilder,
FormControl,
FormGroup,
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
Validators,
    } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
 })

export class AppComponent  {
 public addForm: FormGroup;
 public someWork;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
     private myService: ContactService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.addForm = this.fb.group({
     hours: [null],
     minutes: [null],
    });
  }

 public onSubmit(): void {
  this.someWork = this.addForm.value;
   this.someWork.duration = 
      `${this.addForm.value.hours}:${this.addForm.value.minutes}`;
   console.log(this.someWork);
    this.ContactService.addWorkers(this.someWork);
  }
}
```

I want display the `duration` as `hours` and `minutes` in another form  to edit the `duration`. How can i display `hours` and `minutes` in separate fields by fethcing from **api**.
Like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you notice the typo in your JSON file? It is named 'duartion' instead of 'duration'.

Comment: I apologize, While posting i made mistake.@Sjoerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string from the JSON. An example:

```
const durationArray = duration.split(':'); // Will return an array
// durationArray[0] = hours, durationArray[1] = minutes
this.addForm.value.hours = durationArray[0];
this.addForm.value.minutes = durationArray[1];
```

Comment: I edited with a short example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-vp8jpw